# Problem loading datapump to table with Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

how can i import to one data pump file to table in Oracle data integrator?
i have on local directory 
i should read file(data Pump) from this directory 
and import to table in oracle.
By Oracle Data Integrator How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

To import a dumpfile you must run the "[impdp](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D11E340E-14C6-43B8-AB09-6335F0C1F71B.htm#SUTIL300)" command.

There are a few ways you can make ODI do that for you:

1. You can create a shell script file that calls the impdp with all necessary parameters and create an ODI package (using [OdiOSCommand](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odirf/oracle-data-integrator-tools.html#GUID-3D5C7F77-009B-4010-B111-1539BB5540BB)) that simply runs the shell script. For this to work your ODI agent must have access to the script and also to the database client (or the database home) so it can run impdp. (you can also use OdiOSCommand to run impdp directly)
2. The same idea from step 1 can be done using an ODI Procedure (if maybe the import is just part of a bigger integration flow)
3. ODI also has an [LKM that uses Data Pump](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/using-oracle-data-pump-in-oracle-data-integrator-odi/), but it is used to export a source table into a dumpfile and import it into a target database... If you have access to the source table metadata inside ODI Studio, you can create a simple mapping between source and target tables, choose to use the Data Pump LKM and simulate the execution. ODI will create all the necessary code to import the dumpfile